# Product Safety Testing - EU

Tags: safety, testing, production

I was recently hit with the thought as to what safety tests a domestic electronic product has to go through before it is sold to consumers more specifically in the EU?

I have been looking through online but there is no clear answer. It mentions CE testing, but are there any other regulations/tests before it is sold to consumers and how do they work?

For example, as I look at a USB Power Supply I see it has the CE mark and other logos as well. I should mention that I was looking into EU laws.

Comment: This is a broad question but, I think, not quite broad enough to be closed as too broad. Do edit the question to mention your locale earlier, though, because I skimmed through it and was about to comment that it depends on where the device is being sold before I noticed you mentioned that important detail in an aside in the very last sentence of your question.

Comment: @Hearth Thank you for mentioning that. I’ve edited the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best aproach is indeed to look into EU law (like you already suggested):

https://europa.eu/youreurope/business/selling-in-eu/selling-goods-services/selling-products-eu/index_en.htm

which (regarding safety) links to

https://europa.eu/youreurope/business/product/product-rules-specifications/index_en.htm

which links eventually to (only) CE marking.

Regarding those other logos: they're likely certifications for other regions (FCC for USA, CSA for Canada etc) or logos for product identification (e.g.Class II lasers) etc.

Answer (score 0):

Or in the UK next month you'll be needing the UKCA mark.... https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/prepare-to-use-the-ukca-mark-after-brexit/using-the-ukca-marking-if-the-uk-leaves-the-eu-without-a-deal

Comment: The urge to make products smaller and smaller will cease soon. The minimum dimensions will be reached due to yet another set of symbols required to be shown :)